# Freeform Plugin: Get Total No. of Pages

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, freeform

How does one get the total no. of pages for a multi-step form? The following doesn't work.

```
{% set count = form.pages().count() %}
```

Comment: try {% set page_count = form.pages|length %}